# org.springframework.dao.QueryTimeoutException in spring mvc

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to read all the tickets on the database and displaying them and this is the **my method** in my controller class and as you can see i tried without using the userID but still.

Please Help

```
public ArrayList<TicketModel> getAllTickets(int userID) {
    String sql = "select * from tblticket where fkusername=?";
    //ArrayList<TicketModel> tickets = (ArrayList<TicketModel>) template.query(sql, new TicketModelMapper());
    ArrayList<TicketModel> tickets = (ArrayList<TicketModel>) template.query(sql, new Object[]{userID}, new TicketModelMapper());
    return tickets;
}
```

**This is the error I am getting**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.QueryTimeoutException
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.<init>(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.<init>(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:96)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.getExceptionTranslator(JdbcAccessor.java:99)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:658)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:693)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:725)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:735)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:785)
    com.database.accessobjects.TicketDao.getAllTickets(TicketDao.java:63)
    com.pack.controllers.TicketController.viewAllTickets(TicketController.java:66)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Which spring Version do you use?

Comment: Do you have the spring-Transaction.jar in your classpath?

Comment: Yes I do have it

Comment: Do you use maven? if yess please post your pom.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the container is not able to load the class file QueryTimeoutException.

The file comes with `spring-tx-X.RELEASE.jar`

add this dependency in

```
           <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
              <version>{spring-version}</version>
           </dependency>
```

EDIT 1:
put these in pom.xml if you are using maven. Please replace {spring-version} with your spring version.

Comment: Where do I put these lines? on the web.xml or servlet.xml

Comment: No I am using spring MVC on eclipse

Comment: If you're not using Maven then you can download it from maven repository and add it to lib folder.

Comment: What do I have to download ?

Comment: download the spring-tx jar file.